# What is maximum limit of data can be set through jQuery html() method

Tags: jquery, html, innerhtml

I am changing the div content through jQuery `.html()` method once I get the response text from Ajax event.

Sometimes I get more response data (contains html and script and about to 4MB data). It does take more time to set the response data as div content using jQuery `.html()` method.

Can somebody tell me the reason? Are there any solution or alternatives?

Comment: I think you have a bigger problem. For instance, why do you need the browser to load 4MB of html at once?

Comment: We are handling ajax events through out page. So entire page data has to be updated for every event.

Comment: Wrong answer. You need to seriously reconsider your strategy.

Comment: This is not a normal web application. Its an SAP Business application.Technically we explored a lot and made a decision this way.This is the only way we can achieve that functionality.

Comment: a 4mb of html File ??? is it Oxford dictionary ? lolz. you need to re think the design ideas

Comment: @RamaRaoM - that is apparently why some of these enterprise applications really suck then.  It's a very bad design choice to be regularly updating 4MB of HTML.  There are many other design choices.

Comment: That doesn't matter. If you have to update 4MB of html, do a full page refresh, and pray the browser doesn't crash from your overloaded design. From what you have said in this question I give you 200% odds your app will fail.

Comment: @jfriend00 - +100 to your comment. I am continually appalled by the quality of "enterprise" applications. To the OP; you should strongly consider a new question on to how to avoid this "need". There *is* a better way.

Comment: "Technically we explored a lot and made a decision this way", then you explored very poorly.

Comment: @Fresheyeball instead of a rude comment, you can give a better idea. I may not be more intelligent than you. I explored utmost what I could.This is a stage for sharing knowledge but not for useless comments...

Comment: @RamaRaoM - we would need a LOT more information about what your application is doing to know more explicitly what to recommend.  The answer probably includes, incremental updates using smaller amounts of JSON data, incremental DOM changes rather than 4MB of HTML, rethought UI that doesn't try to put 4MB of HTML on one screen or modify 4MB of data at once, etc...

Comment: @jfriend00 Sure.definitely I will give the detailed info...I hope by today evening I could edit this post with detailed scenario... Thanks for your kind reply and valuable time.. :)

Comment: @RamaRaoM this site is NOT for questions of architectural design. Its about solving, finite and falsifiable problems. Give http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ a shot. Its a better place to ask questions of 'how should this be constructed?' rather than 'I have X problem'.

Comment: @Fresheyeball I would have really appreciated you if this is your first comment. Anyway thanks for your kind suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

First off, regularly downloading and inserting 4MB of HTML is NEVER going to make for a fast, interactive application.  It's going to be a network hog and a memory hog and not perform well.

There is no technical limit to the `.html()` method other than how much memory the browser can get access to.  `.html()` is a shell on top of the native `.innerHTML` property which has no particular limits.

4MB of HTML takes a significant time to download and a significant time for the browser to parse.  That's probably the delay you see.  The time is probably not related to jQuery.  After a little initial housekeeping which has nothing to do with the actual content you are setting, jQuery just sets the `.innerHTML` property and the browser handles parsing the HTML content you gave it.

Now, if you are replacing a large amount of HTML (e.g. another 4MB set of HTML), then jQuery might be a lot slower because it has to traverse every element in the old content and make sure it has cleaned up any jQuery state associated with those elements that are about to be removed.

---

You really ought to fix your page design/app design so that you don't have to use 4MB of HTML.

Comment: Oh..ok.But can you let me know that the browser limits of IE and Chrome?

Comment: I have debugged the script where I could find that jQuery.html() method takes more time.

Comment: @RamaRaoM - there are no hardcoded browser limits that I'm aware of.  It likely depends upon how much RAM and swap space you have on your given computer.  Mobile browsers would typically have access to a lot less memory than desktop browsers.  You really need to fix your page design or app design so you aren't using 4MB of HTML!